# In HistoryPage posts = list(q) NameError: name 'q' is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, nameerror

```
class HistoryPage(BlogHandler):
    def get(self, path):
        q = Page.by_path(path)
        q.fetch(limit = 100)

    posts = list(q)
    if posts:
        self.render("history.html" , path = path, posts = posts)

    else:
        self.redirect("/_edit" + path)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an indentation error. Line `posts = list(q)` and lines after it should go inside the `get` method:

```
class HistoryPage(BlogHandler):
    def get(self, path):
        q = Page.by_path(path)
        q.fetch(limit = 100)

        posts = list(q)
        if posts:
            self.render("history.html" , path = path, posts = posts)   
        else:
            self.redirect("/_edit" + path)
```